# Where does target_link_libraries look for the required files?

Tags: c++, cmake, build, target-link-libraries

I am building a project from source and am trying to understand what is happening in the [CMakeLists.txt](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#organization) files.

Where exactly is *target_link_libraries* looking for the required library files?

The specific CMakeLists.txt file I have has:

```
target_link_libraries(MyApplication PRIVATE
Magnum::Application
Magnum::GL
Magnum::Magnum
Magnum::Shaders)
```

I found folders that have the names *GL* and *Shaders* in a directory called *Magnum* in the project, and they have a collection of header files in them. I believed that target_link_libraries is telling CMake to include the libraries in the *GL* and *Shaders* folder.

However, I cannot seem to find a corresponding folder for *Application*, hence my line of reasoning must be flawed.
I do know *target_link_libraries* is doing something related to allowing the finally-put-together program to be able to use a set of libraries.

What exactly does target_link_libraries do? Where does it look for the required files in order to be able to use the libraries it needs to?

Comment: Read docs for `target_link_libraries` and imported targets. It has everything you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

`target_link_libraries` doesn't link anything automatically. You should have a target previously created via `add_library` (or `add_executable`), where all files are listed.

The way these targets added into your CMake project may differ. E.g. you may have a library source files with **CMakeLists.txt** configuration (where the said `add_library` command is) under some folder `libs/mylib`. Then in your **CMakeLists.txt** you may have the library added with `add_subdirectory(libs/mylib)`. Another option is to add the library with `find_package`.

Comment: _"You should have a target previously created <...>"_ — not necessarily. You can link libraries without creating targets, just files.

Comment: @ixSci fair enough, however it doesn't seem that OP has the files listed under `target_link_libraries`, otherwise this question would not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, you pass targets to `target_link_libraries()`. Targets with a shape like `Magnum::Application` etc are either imported targets or ALIAS targets.
From what you say, it seems than Magnum is vendored into your project, so I guess your are linking ALIAS targets, like the one defined here https://github.com/mosra/magnum/blob/cfc02599e54e02337dd56bb61f70b2e61eb9ce8d/src/Magnum/CMakeLists.txt#L295

Targets defined by `add_library()` or `add_executable()` in CMake are an abstraction carrying several informations, including location of files.